# Custom Server Controls - Base Classes & Usage

Tags: asp.net, custom-server-controls

I hope someone out there can shed some light on the topic of creating server controls, the control base classes and the usage of those classes.

Here is an example of what I want to achieve. I want to create a custom panel control that one can instantiate in the ASPX markup like so:

```
<acme:Panel ID="MyPanel" runtat="server" Scrolling="true">
  <Header>My Panel Header</Header>
  <Toolbars>
    <acme:Toolbar ID="Toolbar1" runat="server"/>
    <acme:Toolbar ID="Toolbar2" runat="server"/>
  </Toolbars>
  <Contents>
    <%-- Some Content for the Contents section --%>
  </Contents>
  <Footer>
    <%-- Some Content for the Footer section --%>
  </Footer>
</acme:Panel>
```

It should render the following HTML:

```
<div id="MyPanel" class="panel scroll-contents">
  <div class="panel-header">
    <div class="panel-header-l"></div>
    <div class="panel-header-c">
      <div class="panel-header-wrapper">My Panel Header</div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-header-r"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-toolbars">
    // HTML of Toolbar control
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    <div class="panel-body-t">
      <div class="panel-body-tl"></div>
      <div class="panel-body-tc"></div>
      <div class="panel-body-tr"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body-m">
      <div class="panel-body-ml"></div>
      <div class="panel-body-mc">
        <div class="panel-body-wrapper">
          // Contents
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body-mr"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body-b">
      <div class="panel-body-bl"></div>
      <div class="panel-body-bc"></div>
      <div class="panel-body-br"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-footer">
    <div class="panel-footer-l"></div> 
    <div class="panel-footer-c">
      <div class="panel-footer-wrapper">
        // Footer contents
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-footer-r"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The developer should be able to omit any of the sections except the Contents section. Omitted sections' HTML should not be rendered. Plus the user should be able to instantiate/add a Panel control in the code behind of the page and add additional controls to the various sections of the Panel control, like so:

```
ACME.Panel MyPanel = new ACME.Panel();
MyPlaceHolder.Controls.Add(MyPanel);

MyPanel.Header = "My Panel Header";

MyPanel.Toolbars.Controls.Add(new ACME.Toolbar());

MyPanel.Footer.Controls.Add(new Literal());

MyPanel.Contents.Controls.Add(new GridView());
```

I have read the following article : Communications Sector Conversations : Authoring Custom ASP.NET Server Controls (Which base class?)

Since I do not really want the developer to change the styling of my control, the System.Web.UI.Control base class should be sufficient, but I will also need to apply the INamingContainer interface. Thus my control should look like so:

```
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.Design;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.Design;
using System.Security.Permissions;
namespace ACME
{
    [ToolboxData("&lt;{0}:Panel runat=server></{0}:Panel >")]
    [ParseChildren(true)]
    public class Panel : Control, INamingContainer
    {
        private string _header;
        private ITemplate _toolbars;
        private ITemplate _contents;
        private ITemplate _footerContents;
        public DialogBox()
        {
        }
        [Browsable(false),
        PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerProperty)]
        public virtual ITemplate Toolbars
        {
            get { return _toolbars; }
            set { _toolbars = value; }
        }
        [Browsable(false),
        PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerProperty)]
        public virtual ITemplate Contents
        {
            get { return _contents; }
            set { _contents= value; }
        }
        [Browsable(false),
        PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerProperty)]
        public virtual ITemplate Footer
        {
            get { return _footerContents; }
            set { _footerContents = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

I have read many tutorials but they either don't cover my intended implementation or explain WHY a certain approach was taken. They have also confused me so much that I have resorted to JavaScript to dynamically render the necessary HTML. If there are any Control Guru's out there, could you please explain how you would have tackled this task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is going to be a long one, a lot of code to follow:

Because you have a lot of common elements that you want rendered out, I started with a BaseControl that defined some common methods to generate all the divs you're after. This inherits from [System.Web.UI.Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.aspx) - as the docs state:

> This is the primary class that you derive from when you develop custom ASP.NET server controls. **Control** does not have any user interface (UI) specific features. If you are authoring a control that does not have a UI, or combines other controls that render their own UI, derive from **Control**.

So the base control looks like this:

```
/// <summary>
/// Provides some common methods.
/// </summary>
public class BaseControl: Control
{
    protected Control[] TempControls;

    /// <summary>
    /// Clears the child controls explicitly, and stores them locally.
    /// </summary>
    protected void ClearControls()
    {
        if (HasControls())
        {
            TempControls = new Control[Controls.Count];
            Controls.CopyTo(TempControls, 0);
        }

        Controls.Clear();
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a new panel (HTML div) with the requested CSS 
    /// and containing any controls passed in.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="cssClass">The CSS class to be applied</param>
    /// <param name="controls">Any controls that should be added to the panel</param>
    protected Panel NewPanel(string cssClass, params Control[] controls)
    {
        // Create a new Panel, assign the CSS class.
        var panel = new Panel { CssClass = cssClass };

        // Loop through the controls adding them to the panel.
        foreach (var control in controls)
        {
            panel.Controls.Add(control);
        }

        return panel;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a new row of panels (HTML div), based on the CSS class prefix.
    /// The center panel holds the controls passed in.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="cssClassPrefix"></param>
    /// <param name="controls"></param>
    protected Panel NewRow(string cssClassPrefix, params Control[] controls)
    {
        // Expaned for clarity, but could all be passed in on one call.
        var row = NewPanel(cssClassPrefix);
        row.Controls.Add(NewPanel(cssClassPrefix + "-l"));
        row.Controls.Add(NewPanel(cssClassPrefix + "-c", controls));
        row.Controls.Add(NewPanel(cssClassPrefix + "-r"));

        return row;
    }
}
```

You then need to create some controls that will handle each of your templates, I've created two here.

First up, a control that will generate a single row - used by both the header and footer:

```
public class AcmeSimple : BaseControl, INamingContainer
{
    private string m_CssPrefix;

    public AcmeSimple(string cssPrefix)
    {
        m_CssPrefix = cssPrefix;
    }

    protected override void CreateChildControls()
    {

        ClearControls();

        Panel wrapper = NewPanel(m_CssPrefix + "-wrapper", TempControls);

        Panel simple = NewRow(m_CssPrefix, wrapper);

        Controls.Add(simple);

        base.CreateChildControls();
    }
}
```

It creates a new panel to hold the controls, and then creates a new row of divs to hold the wrapper.

Then a slightly more complex contents control, that works on the same principle as the header:

```
public class AcmeContents: BaseControl, INamingContainer
{
    protected override void CreateChildControls()
    {
        ClearControls();

        Panel wrapper = NewPanel("panel-body-wrapper", TempControls);

        Panel contents = NewPanel("panel-body");
        contents.Controls.Add(NewRow("panel-body-t"));
        contents.Controls.Add(NewRow("panel-body-m", wrapper));
        contents.Controls.Add(NewRow("panel-body-b"));

        Controls.Add(contents);

        base.CreateChildControls();
    }
}
```

So this one just created three rows, the middle one of which contains the controls.

Finally, the actual control that you place on the page:

```
[ParseChildren(true)]
[ToolboxData("<{0}:AcmeControl runat=server></{0}:AcmeControl>")]
public class AcmeControl: BaseControl, INamingContainer
{

    public bool Scrolling { get; set; }

    [TemplateContainer(typeof(AcmeSimple))]
    public ITemplate Header { get; set; }
    [TemplateContainer(typeof(AcmeContents))]
    public ITemplate Contents { get; set; }
    [TemplateContainer(typeof(AcmeSimple))]
    public ITemplate Footer { get; set; }

    protected override void CreateChildControls()
    {
        Controls.Clear();

        string cssClass = "panel";

        if (Scrolling)
        {
            cssClass += " scrollContents";
        }

        Panel panel = NewPanel(cssClass);
        panel.ID = ID;
        Controls.Add(panel);

        if (Header != null)
        {
            var header = new AcmeHeader("panel-header");
            Header.InstantiateIn(header);
            panel.Controls.Add(header);
        }

        if (Contents != null)
        {
            var contents = new AcmeContents();
            Contents.InstantiateIn(contents);
            panel.Controls.Add(contents);
        }
        else
        {
            // Possibly a little harsh, as it's a runtime exception.
            throw new ArgumentNullException("Contents", "You must supply a contents template.");
        }

        if (Footer != null)
        {
            var footer = new AcmeSimple("panel-footer");
            Footer.InstantiateIn(footer);
            panel.Controls.Add(footer);
        }
    }
}
```

So we define the templates that we support as properties of the control, along with the Scrollable property you wanted. Then, in CreateChildControls we start building up the body of the control using the controls we created at the begining and the methods in the BaseControl.

This goes onto the page like this:

```
<cc1:AcmeControl ID="AcmeControl1" runat="server">
  <Header>
     <b>Here's a header</b>
  </Header>
  <Contents>
     <i>Here's some controls in the content.</i>
  </Contents>
</cc1:AcmeControl>
```

And renders out like this:

```
<div id="AcmeControl1_AcmeControl1" class="panel">
    <div class="panel-header">
        <div class="panel-header-l">
        </div>
        <div class="panel-header-c">
            <div class="panel-header-wrapper">
                <b>Here's a header</b>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-header-r">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="panel-body-t">
            <div class="panel-body-t-l">
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body-t-c">
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body-t-r">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body-m">
            <div class="panel-body-m-l">
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body-m-c">
                <div class="panel-body-wrapper">
                    <i>Here's some controls in the content.</i>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body-m-r">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body-b">
            <div class="panel-body-b-l">
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body-b-c">
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body-b-r">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So the only difference is that the contents styles are t-l rather than tl.

However (and this could be a big issue for you), template controls aren't really designed to be filled from code-behind - you'll notice that trying to write:

```
AcmeControl1.Footer.Controls.Add([...]);
```

won't compile.

What you can do however is call:

```
AcmeControl1.Footer = Page.LoadTemplate([...])
```

and pass in the path to an **ascx** file.

Further reading on creating templated controls can be found:

- [System.Web.UI.ITemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.itemplate.aspx)
- [How to: Create Templated ASP.NET User Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36574bf6.aspx)
- [How to: Create Templates Dynamically in DataList Web Server Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6d5z5yty.aspx)

I said it would be long.